# IK issue when hand is near face

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I'm not entirely sure if I have a clear title but I provided some images to show what my current problem is.

[image]
[image]

Here's how the pose looks like. As you can see, the elbow is too high. I tried to move pole target to counter it, but it's not affecting it. What could be a good way to fix this?

I've added the file so you guys can check it if you want

[image]

Comment: The issue seems quite straight forward, the elbow needs to be fully open in order for the hand to reach that pose. The solution would be to either adapt your model and rig to the pose, or adapt the pose to the limita of your model and rig. The later is more often than not the most usited.in your case, i'd say a real human would not have his shoulders and spine square straight like you did, which is part if how we manage to do that when fencing.

Comment: Are you sure the hands are in the correct position? The hand palms of both hands point to the outside of the body.

Comment: @L0Lock I didn't quite get what you meant with square straight at first, which got me confused. That's something I didn't consider at first, the model was mostly for testing purposes so I just made it simple. Quite disappointing that I might have to change a pose that I thought was possible.

Comment: I mean that, the spine and shoulders poses are extremely straight and at square angles, that just not a pose that mechanically works with a human body. So unless you want to use wayarounds like stretching or dislocating limbs, you can't expect to make this work. Also check your limbs lenghts, it might be too short to being with, which doesn't help either.

Comment: @L0Lock oh, ok. I got that wrong again lol. I did move the shoulders as it looked weird that the arms were too close to the body. I just moved them to the side, of course, mirrored. I'll see if moving them in would fix it

Comment: I regenerated the rig from my backup metarig which I didn't move the shoulders and the issue is still there. I added a fresh metarig to double check and my shoulder position and limb lengths are the same as the fresh one

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the pole angle to either 90 or -90. I get this issue a lot on my models when the elbow poles aren't at -90 and also make sure your bones aren't completely level and straight or they will not bend and behave correctly.

Comment: I'm quite sure that I fixed the roll. Just checked it and corrected the rolls, still the same result

Comment: Nothing in the blender file, no objects in layers.

Comment: I just downloaded the file and it's exactly what I uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are enabling IK_Stretch=1, allowing the armature (and mesh) to stretch beyond what it can attain. Try setting IK Stretch to 0:

[image]

and you'll see that your pose goal might be impossible for your armature -- is why the arm is straight and not bent, and the arm is actually stretched.

[image]

Comment: On the first rig I made, I did turn off IK Stretch. On the current one, turning it off still doesn't really give my expected result